# IOS Photos - Requesting Image for Asset with Swift

Tags: ipad, swift, ios8, photokit

I have updated this post on 10 April 2015 with new info ...

I have an App where I am copying the contents of a Cloud Photo album to a local Album on an IOS device. I am using the following code :

```
func fetchFullSizeImageForAsset(asset:PHAsset)  -> (UIImage)? {                                                                    // get the image from an asset ( could be nil )

    var myImage:UIImage?

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.synchronous = true
    requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat

    let screenSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let targetSize = CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)

    let imageManager = PHImageManager()
    imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset as PHAsset, targetSize: targetSize,                                             // targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, gives a null image !
        contentMode: .AspectFit, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
            (result, info) -> Void in
            myImage = result
    })
    return myImage
}
```

My idea is to get myImage with the above code, and copy it to a new local album.

This gives me a low quality image (256 x 256) some of the time, but sometimes I get a high quality image (640 x 640).
I have looked at the Cloud Album images in the new Photos app on 10.10.3, and they are all high quality (640 x 640)

When I use photos to look at the shared album on the iPad, the images only become high quality when I click on them - which is the expected behaviour.

What is baffling me is that all these manually clicked images then import in high quality when I rerun my App !

Is this a bug in PhotoKit on IOS8 or am I missing something ?